# Check variable if explode-able in PHP

Tags: php

Not sure if there is a way to check a variable if it is explode-able or not...

I have a database of city names some are one word cities and some are multiple word cities

EX: Chicago, Los Angeles

I keep getting an error when use "implode" when a city name is one word, so I tried using "count" and using an if statement... not having any luck

```
$citi = explode(' ', $row['city']);
$count = count($citi);
if ($count > 1) {
   $city = implode('+', $citi);
}
else {
   $city = $citi;
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
if(strpos($row['city'], ' ') !== false) {
  // explodable
} else {
  // not explodable
}
```

Answer (score 14):

use explode itself to see if it is explodable

```
$a = explode(" ","Where Am I?");
if(count($a)>1) {
     echo "explodable";
}
else {
     echo "No use of exploding";
}
```

Comment: Very nice. its much handy then all other methods.

Answer (score 0):

explode() always returns an array, whether it exploded something or not.

```
$a = explode(' ', 'Chicago');
print_r($a); 
// output: array('Chicago')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, definitely can be done. Try [stristr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php)

```
if( stristr( $row['city'], ' ' ) )
    // It has a space, therefore explodable
```

It loos like you're trying to turn the spaces into '+'.

I would just use a [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$city = str_replace( ' ', '+', $row['city'] );
```

Comment: HA! I did't even think to use str_replace that would have been a lot easier.  Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most efficient way. I have implemented this.

```
$name = $_POST["address_name"];
if(strpos($row['city'], ' ') !== false) {
  // explodable
  list($fname, $lname) = explode(' ', $name);
} else {
  // not explodable
  $fname = $name;
  $lname = $name;
}
```